# Mousemove giving wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, gsap

Good day! I have a problem with my little project. What I wish to achieve is whenever I hover my mouse on my fishing area, an indicator will appear. However, tt seems to be giving wrong coordinates on *mousemove* event, or maybe I'm wrong. I have here my [codepen](https://codepen.io/karmablackshaw/pen/zYxXmoQ?editors=1111).

> HTML

```
<div class="game-content">
  <div class="pond">
    <div id="circle" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="pond__fishing-area" class="pond__fishing-area"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
    let circleRect = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
    let wrapper = document.getElementById("pond__fishing-area");
    let wrapperRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();

    function moveCircle(e) {
      gsap.to(circle, 0.3, {
        css: {
          left: e.clientX,
          top: e.clientY
        }
      });
    }
    wrapper.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      gsap.to(circle, 0.4, { scale: 1, autoAlpha: 1 });
      wrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCircle);
    });

    wrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      gsap.to(circle, 0.4, { scale: 0.1, autoAlpha: 0 });
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: onpond class, `position: relative;` calculated the wrong position. can you remove this anyway?

Comment: okay sir, lemme try

Comment: I have updated it sir @hasan05, however the ball loses opacity on move.

Comment: you can condition `mouseout` event and also @anyman morsy's answer also will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the *css* properties of your pond which is `position: relative` gives you wrong coordinates, remove this.

Answer (score 1):

As **pond** is positioned **relatively**, so **circle** is getting positioned incorrectly so while positioning circle in `moveCircle()`. We need to position the **circle** **relatively** to the **pond**. i.e. we need to deduct pond's position from client's position. `moveCircle()` will look like this:

```
  function moveCircle(e) {
        let position=document.getElementById("circle").parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
// position will contain the position of pond
          gsap.to(circle, 1, {
            css: {
              left: e.clientX-position.x,// giving relative position to circle
              top: e.clientY-position.y
            }
          });
        }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    let circle = document.getElementById("circle");
    let circleRect = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
    let wrapper = document.getElementById("pond__fishing-area");
    let wrapperRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();

    function moveCircle(e) {
    let position=document.getElementById("circle").parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
// position will contain the position of pond

      gsap.to(circle, 1, {
        css: {
          left: e.clientX-position.x, // giving relative position to circle
          top: e.clientY-position.y
        }
      });
    }
    wrapper.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      gsap.to(circle, 0.4, { scale: 1, autoAlpha: 1 });
      wrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCircle);
    });

    wrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      gsap.to(circle, 0.4, { scale: 0.1, autoAlpha: 0 });
    });
  }
})
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.game-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.game-content .circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.game-content .pond {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
          position:relative;
}
.game-content .pond .pond__fishing-area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="game-content">
    <div class="pond">
      <div id="circle" class="circle"></div>
      <div id="pond__fishing-area" class="pond__fishing-area"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: one problem, when you slowly move the circle, I think @Ayman Morsy gives an good solution

Comment: @hasan05, yupp, I noticed it gets stuck on slow move.

Answer (score 1):

based on @hasan05 do this and it will fix your issue:

- from class `.pond` **remove** `position: relative;`
- at class `.circle` **add**  `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: sir, with position relative gone, how can I position the child of pond base on pond ?

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` gives wrong calculation.

remove this and design other way.

and also change this event,

```
       wrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {      
        var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
          if(e == circle) {
            return;
          }
          gsap.to(circle, 0.4, { scale: 0.1, autoAlpha: 0 });
        });
```

Comment: btw, with position relative gone, I can no longer position my *div.pond_fishing-area* inside the pond.